# Classification by row

Tags: r

I want to make a classification of my dataframe of which here is an extract. Indeed on each row I want to classify the columns.

```
require(tidyverse)
df <-   rbind(c(0.97, 0.97, 0.95, 0.90),
                  c(0.91, 0.92 ,0.92, 0.92),
                  c(0.98, 0.91, 0.92, 0.92),
                  c(0.89, 0.89, 0.91 ,0.90),
                  c(0.82, 0.95, 0.88, 0.87),
                  c(0.86, 0.97, 0.95, 0.91)) %>% data.frame
colnames(df) <- c("M1","M2", "M3" ,"M4")
rownames(df) <- paste0("P_", 1:6)
```

Here is the expected result.

```
df
      M1   M2   M3   M4             CLASS
P_1 0.97 0.97 0.95 0.90 M1 = M2 > M3 > M4
P_2 0.91 0.92 0.92 0.92 M2 = M3 = M4 > M1
P_3 0.98 0.91 0.92 0.92 M1 > M3 = M4 > M2
P_4 0.89 0.89 0.91 0.90 M3 > M4 > M1 = M2
P_5 0.82 0.95 0.88 0.87 M2 > M3 > M4 > M1
P_6 0.86 0.97 0.95 0.91 M2 > M3 > M4 > M1
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this with dplyr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df$CLASS=apply(df,1,function(x){
  tmp=sort(x,decreasing=T)
  part1=head(rep(names(tmp),each=2),-1)
  part2=ifelse(diff(as.numeric(tmp))<0,">","=")
  part1[seq(2,length(part1),2)]=part2
  paste(part1,collapse=" ")
})

      M1   M2   M3   M4             CLASS
P_1 0.97 0.97 0.95 0.90 M1 = M2 > M3 > M4
P_2 0.91 0.92 0.92 0.92 M2 = M3 = M4 > M1
P_3 0.98 0.91 0.92 0.92 M1 > M3 = M4 > M2
P_4 0.89 0.89 0.91 0.90 M3 > M4 > M1 = M2
P_5 0.82 0.95 0.88 0.87 M2 > M3 > M4 > M1
P_6 0.86 0.97 0.95 0.91 M2 > M3 > M4 > M1
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your proposition, Is it possible to do this with dplyr

Comment: @dici I don't know dplyr.

Comment: ok, i want to understand the contents of the tmp variable.

Comment: @dici You can try running the commands on one row of the df and see for yourself, what is going on. In `tmp` is saved the sorted row, from highest to lowest.